# Firebase Storage Exceed Quota Limit

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, quota

"Could not load files; quota has been exceeded for this project? written in my Firebase Storage. I have read some posts about need to delete the files/photos in the storage or upgrade the limit to solve this problem. So, I would like to ask if anyone knows how to delete the photo in storage since, after I exceeded the limit, Firebase Storage does not show any folder or files for me to edit or delete. Even I goto the user's folder manually, still, it does not shows any picture.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support for assistance if you're not able to get the Firebase console to work as you expect.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've exceeded your bandwidth quota for a day, most likely on a project that is on Firebase's free/Flame plan.

If you wait until tomorrow, the quota will reset and you should be able to read and delete files again (until you go over the daily quota again of course).

Alternatively, you can upgrade to the paid plan, and you'll immediately be able to read and write the files again.